# Cannot install Nvidia graphics driver

Tags: 12.10, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu 12.10.When I tried to install nvidia drivers the following errors occurred. Please help.
Can I use Nvidia drivers with Unity?

```
khat33b@Oa:~$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates
[sudo] password for khat33b: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nvidia-current-updates
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/67.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 204 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-current-updates.
(Reading database ... 155992 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking nvidia-current-updates (from .../nvidia-current-updates_304.51-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up nvidia-current-updates (304.51-0ubuntu1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-current-updates/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-current-updates/alt_ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
INFO:Enable nvidia-current-updates
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Processing quirk ThinkPad T420s
DEBUG:Failure to match Dell Inc. with LENOVO
DEBUG:Quirk doesn't match
DEBUG:Processing quirk Latitude E6530
DEBUG:Failure to match Inspiron N5110 with Latitude E6530
DEBUG:Quirk doesn't match
Loading new nvidia-current-updates-304.51 DKMS files...
Building only for 3.5.0-17-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Module build for the currently running kernel was skipped since the
kernel source for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-17-generic
```

I have Dell Inspiron N5110, RAM 3.8GB, Processor Intel® Core™ i5-2430M CPU @ 2.40GHz × 4, Graphics is shown Unknown, 64bit OS.

The result of `lspci |grep VGA` is:

```
khat33b@Oa:~$ lspci |grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 540M] (rev a1)
```

Also, Ubuntu has experienced an internal error window keeps on popping up. On clicking show details, The executable path is `/usr/share/apport/apport-gpu-error-intel.py.` There are also many other details.It's a pretty huge list!

Another window also appears:
    Apport has detected a possible GPU hang.  Did your system recently lock up and/or require a hard reboot?

Comment: what is your hardware? please edit your question and put result of `lspci |grep VGA`

Comment: This question is 6 years old. Are you sure you don't want to delete it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this nvidia-section at ubuntu.com?

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

I believe it would help you solve most problems with nvidia-cards in an ubuntu environment.

Comment: This will not work as I have an Nvidia Optimus card. I tried installing bumblebee but nvidia does not show in dash; from the terminal nvidia shows installed

Comment: oh ok. It appears that there are problems with Optimus cards. There are several posts about it scattered around. I dont know if it can be solved or will be solved in the near future. But I found this interesting list at nVidias own site: ftp://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/310.19/README/supportedchips.html It lists supported cards in a Linuxx86 environment. It would always be a good idea to check compatibility before buying. This holds true especially with graphic cards.

Comment: What happens if you run "optirun glxspheres" in terminal? Maybe it works..